# how to get the 3rd index in a foreach iteration c#

Tags: unity, c#

here is my code

```
string[] strData = {"P  ","B  ","P  ","PB ","P  ",P  "};
string OriginalData ="";
 for(int i = 0; i < strData.Length; i++){
     OriginalData += strData[i];
     OriginalData += ",";
  }
string[] newNewData = strData.Split(',');
 //i want to get the 3rd index from inside the foreach
  foreach(string newStrData in newNewData){
      //display the 3rd index
  }
```

What i did here was split my string so that i can parse them 1 by 1 later for my conditional statement . 
what i want here is that i want to get the 3rd index inside of my variable `newStrData` .

Comment: Only the 3rd index or a range starting at the 3rd index?

Comment: yes sir for now the 3rd index only

Comment: @slagmoth . ididnt yet accept an answer sir .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have an `IEnumerator` and don't have an `IList` access, you can do this:

```
int i = 0;  
foreach(string newStrData in newNewData)
{
    i++;
    if (i == 3)
    {
         //display the 3rd index
    }
  }
```

If you have `IList` access, *<s>use a `for` loop</s>* use the indexer as `newNewData[2]`.

Comment: how could i display the index sir

Comment: The `i-1` is index here.

Comment: i dont get it how can i display it sir . haha sorry

Comment: `Debug.Log` puts it in the console.

Comment: i mean to display the 3rd index sir . `Debug.Log("The 3rd index is : " + newStrData[i])`?

Comment: `Debug.Log("The item at the 3rd index is : " + newStrData)`

Comment: @Gin09 I am glad I could help but you should try to understand the algorithm behind what is going on rather than looking for ready-made code. It will help you better in the long run.

Comment: lol Gin09 you remind me of Jorji Costava from Papers Please sir :D

Answer (score 1):

Simply put: you can't. The concept of an index it's foreign to `Enumerator`s.

If you need an index, use a `for` loop instead, i.e.:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < newNewData.Length; i++) {
    if (i == 2) {
        // Operate on newNewData[i]
    }
}
```

Note that the `for` loop is useless if you *only* need to do something with the third element of the array and nothing else with the others, of course, you can just access that third element directly with `newNewData[2]`.

Comment: i cant do it like this `for(int i=0;i<newStrData.Length;i++){  if(i == 3) }`

Answer (score 1):

In regular C# you a string is simply a char[] therefore you can do the following:

```
int index = 2;

char x = newStrData[index];

string x = (string)newStrData[index];

Debug.Log($"The item at the 3rd index is : {newStrData[index]}");
```

I honestly don't know which version of C# Unity uses but if it uses string interpolation you can do that without casting to string if you need to log it. Concatenation is typically frowned upon due to the immutability of strings and their memory cost if done a lot.

If it doesn't support interpolation you can do this to avoid concatenation:

```
Debug.Log(string.Format"The item at the 3rd index is : {0}", newStrData[index]);
```

Collections are zero-based for C# as well so to get the 3rd one in a collection you would need to get index 2.

If you wanted a range starting at a given index could use Substring();